# Default Parameter Value to Another Parameter

Tags: c#

I would like to do something like below:

```
private void MyMethod(int param1, int param2 = param1){}
```

The intent is to make param2 optional, and where it is not specified, give it the same value as the first parameter.

Is this possible?

I am aware that I can use nullable types and do the check and assignment in the method body.  I also know I could achieve this through overloading. I specifically want to know if this is possible in the signature.

I'm using .Net 4.0

Thanks

Comment: If there's a simple solution with overloading why not use it?

Comment: @Dmitry If there was a solution without overloading, why not use it!  (Turns out there isn't though - see below)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is this possible?

No. Default values for parameters have to be one of:

- A compile time constant (e.g. a numeric or string literal)
- The default value for the parameter type, e.g. `default(Foo)` or `default` (as of C# 7.1)
- The "zero" values of value types, e.g. `new Guid()`

It's quite restrictive, unfortunately.